# How to make a midlet from source?

Tags: java, java-me, compilation, midp, midlet

Hey I got some sources files for midlet application. How can I compile these to a midlet that I can run on my mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Download Netbeans

Create new project and add your sources to it

Compile and you are done.

[Simple guide to Netbeans for Midlets](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/60/mobility/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Java Mobile project in [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) (version 6.5) from your existing source. Open Netbeans, and open File -> New Project menu. Here is what you see:

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/8241/javame.jpg](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/8241/javame.jpg)

Create project, right click on its name and Deploy. An MIDP jar file is created in project's dist folder.

Comment: And then how do you then get that onto a mobile?

Comment: You can send the jar file to your mobile phone by bluetooth connection, I usually do that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going from memory here, it's been a while since I wrote any mobile java.

Firstly, you need to get the J2ME libraries - that's Java2 Mobile Edition<sup>*</sup>. These contain a subset of the java libraries in addition to some mobile specific packages.

Your application must then implement a class that extends the MIDlet class. The MIDlet class is the interface between the mobile and your application.

Compile and preverify the code, create a manifest and package the whole lot into a JAR file.

Getting the JAR file onto the mobile is very dependant on the handset you're using - not all phone allow you to download applications from a PC, some require special cables.

[Here's a site the goes into more detail.](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/02/09/j2me1.html)

- It seems there's been a update to the name since I was writing midlets.